# Putting React components into a Jekyll site

Tags: reactjs, jekyll

I have two things:

- a React app running locally (using `npm run start`)
- a Jekyll site hosted on github pages

How do I put my React app onto my Jekyll site?

Comment: Just build your app by `npm build`, and put generated files to the jekyll site.

Comment: So `npm build` gives me a subdirectory called `build` which contains `index.html` and `transformed.js`. I tried copying the entire directory into my jekyll site and linking to `...my-react-app/build/index.html`, but it doesn't render any of my components. Could you be a bit more verbose with your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

*@streetturtle* means just copy all the generated files on your `...my-react-app/build/` folder after executing the command `npm build`, and place them into the `branch` of your *username.github.io* where your GitHub Pages site is currently being built, without using Jekyll to generate a static site, at all!

- [Instruction for creating GitHub Pages.](https://pages.github.com/)